# Removing ASCII spaces in spark SQL for multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

am extracting data from the DB and i get ASCII spaces for specific columns, i used trim for those columns but the leading and trailing are not being trimmed. Please help me in creating a function where i can use that function for all the columns that i need to remove the spaces.

am thinking to call the function like this: 
function_name(column_name)

Comment: if you provide your sample data that will help us to resolved issue asap

Comment: the sample data will be like this ............12345 5678 ..........
Dots represent spaces and those are ascii spaces not the regular spaces

Answer (score 0):

Lead/trailing spaces can be removed with Spark function "trim":

```
val df = Seq(
  ("  SpacesBefore", "Spaces after  ")
).toDF("before", "after")

val columnsToTrim = Seq("before", "after")

val result = columnsToTrim.foldLeft(df)((df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, trim(col(colName))))
```